# What should we say to a child when you mean "Where have they injected you"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

> [**in‧ject**](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/inject) /ɪnˈdʒekt/ ●●○ verb [transitive]     1 to put liquid,
>   especially a drug, into someone’s body by using a special needle
>
> inject something into somebody/something
>
> The drug is injected directly into the base of the spine.
>
> inject somebody with something
>
> I have to inject myself with insulin.

Ok, say your wife have just brought your son home after getting him vaccinated (you didn't go there with them). Then, you ask this to your son:

**Where have they injected you?** (I expect the answer such as "into my arm / thigh 
 etc")

My question is

**Do we have a simpler way to express the above question to a child?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Where did they inject you" is an idiomatic way of asking where on the body was the injection administered, and I believe most people would understand what you meant by that. However, it could also be understood to refer to the location that the procedure took place, so you could get the answer "in the doctor's surgery"!

To be more specific (but possibly less idiomatic) you could ask "where did they put the injection?" or "where did they put the needle?"

Comment: I think I mean "where did they put the needle?" into the arm or thigh or something

Comment: @tom Yes, I understand that is what you want to say. Hopefully I have explained that "where did they inject you" is a way of asking that, but it could have dual meaning which I was pointing out.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out also the alternative terms "poke," "stick," and "jab" instead of "inject," which at least in the US often carries a negative connotation.